# how to make a variable to echo this data on ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have ajax code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".monitor").click(function(){

        $("#list-format").html("");
        let nama_puskesmas = $(this).data('nama');
        let id_puskesmas = $(this).data('id');
        let nomor = $(this).data('nomor');
        let base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>'
        

        $.ajax({
            url     : 'get_data',
            method  : 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : {id_puskesmas:id_puskesmas},
            success : function(response){

                $.each(response, function(i, obj){
                    $("#list-format").append("<li>"+obj.format+"</li>");
                });

                $("#title-modal").html(nama_puskesmas);
                $("#exampleModalCenter").modal('show');
                $("#button-submit").html(`<a href="${base_url}dinas/view_monitor/${id_puskesmas}" id="submit_modal" class="btn btn-primary">Lihat data</a>`)
                $("#button-submit2").html(`<a href="https://wa.me/${nomor}?text=Laporan%20Yang%20Masih%20Belum%20Lengkap%20Adalah%20Sebagai%20Berikut%20Ini" id="submit_modal" class="btn btn-primary">Kirim Pesan</a>`)

               
            }


            
        })      

    })
</script>
```

If I run this program, it will view like this:

```
Data yang belum diupload
1.Form Lap PTM
2.Form Lap Posbindu
3.Form Lap IVA
4.Form Lap Jiwa
5.Form Lap Indera dan Gimul
6.Form Lap Diare
7.Form Lap LROA
8.Form Lap Thypoid
9.Form Lap Laporan Hiv Aids dan IMS
10.Form Laporan Hepatitis
```

I will then echo this data to my another function.

How can I make a variable from this code?

```
 $.each(response, function(i, obj){
                    $("#list-format").append("<li>"+obj.format+"</li>");
                });
```

To echo on this  :

```
$("#button-submit2").html(`<a href="https://wa.me/${nomor}?text=Laporan%20Yang%20Masih%20Belum%20Lengkap%20Adalah%20Sebagai%20Berikut%20Ini" id="submit_modal" class="btn btn-primary">Kirim Pesan</a>`)
```

Or can I make an echo to this #button-submit2?

Comment: What is `#button-submit2`?  If it's an actual `<button/>` then putting a link inside of a button is pretty weird.  What are you attempting to do?  What specifically isn't working?

Comment: its a function to show button on modal . it will make a button on Modal with value "kirim pesan" and will open this link https:// bla bla bla .speciffically not working is this data like " data belum diupload . 1.Lap PTM" cant be echo on this #button_submit2 . i dont know how to echo this

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// this var contains a new element, which is not yet appended to the DOM
var $receivedItems = $('<div></div>');
$(".monitor").click(function(){

    $("#list-format").html("");
    let nama_puskesmas = $(this).data('nama');
    let id_puskesmas = $(this).data('id');
    let nomor = $(this).data('nomor');
    let base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>'


    $.ajax({
        url     : 'get_data',
        method  : 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data    : {id_puskesmas:id_puskesmas},
        success : function(response){
            $.each(response, function(i, obj){
                // instead of echoing it directly by appending it to the DOM, store your list items in the hidden or not-appended element in your variable
                $receivedItems.append("<li>"+obj.format+"</li>");
                $("#list-format").append("<li>"+obj.format+"</li>");
            });

            // ..... your other stuff

            var buttonHtml = `<a href="https://wa.me/${nomor}?text=Laporan%20Yang%20Masih%20Belum%20Lengkap%20Adalah%20Sebagai%20Berikut%20Ini" id="submit_modal" class="btn btn-primary">Kirim Pesan</a>`;
            var $button2 = $(buttonHtml);

            $button2.on('click', function(e) {
                // be aware to use href only as a fallback if js does not work. otherwise your url will change and js won’t be executed
                e.preventDefault();
                // on click, you can append the list items stored in $receivedItems
                $("#list-format").append($receivedItems.children());
            });
            // be aware of nesting a and button tags, you shouldn’t
            $("#button-submit2").append($button2);

        }

    })      

})
</script>
```

I put some comments in the code. In this approach you can store all received items in a jQuery object which is not yet appended to a DOM node. It will be by triggering the on-click event which is added to the submit2 button.

Comment: sorry sir , how can its work , i make a button from  ".html" not a ".on(click)" , i just need make a  $.each(response, function(i, obj){
                    $("#list-format").append("<li>"+obj.format+"</li>");
                });      to echo on this  here $("#button-submit2").html(`<a href="https://wa.me/${nomor}?text=Laporan%20Yang%20Masih%20Belum%20Lengkap%20Adalah%20Sebagai%20Berikut%20Ini" //HERE SIR      id="submit_modal" class="btn btn-primary">Kirim Pesan</a>`)

Comment: Hey @AdhikMulat I adjusted the code. Is it the way you want it?

Comment: yes its can save in the variable $receiveditem .but it cant calling at the button submit2 with a function on click . how i can call it like  ${nomor} ?